# Creating a Table of Computed Statistics

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS, and would like to create a table of summary statistics that I compute (not only the usual mean, median, etc.)as shown below:

Statistic (Header Column 1),    Value (Header Column2), Number of Scored Items  ## (Row 1), Number of Examinees ## (Row 2), Mean ##.#%, Median  ##.#%, Standard Deviation   ##.#%, Minimum  ##.#%
Maximum ##.#%, Reliability Estimate #.##, Standard Error of Measurement #.## (Row 9).

I have tried using proc means, but it only allows me to use the summary statistics that's built in the function. So for instance, I don't know how I can use a formula to calculate the Reliability Estimate, and then show it in a table along with other summary stats such as the number of unique observations, etc.

Comment: It depends. If the formula can be calculated from summary stats then you can still use PROC MEANS. Otherwise it may mean running multiple procs and combining the output or doing a manual calculation. At this point we do not have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: The list of automated statistics that can be calculated are listed here: http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1qnc9bddfvhzqn105kqitnf29cp.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n11nn4xu6p9wvjn1lh60wtvvn538